# Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I typed this expression :

```
 let p_one : int ref = ref 1 ;;
 let p_two() : int ref = ref 2 ;;
 let p_three() : int ref = ref 3 ;;
 let accumulate() ( p_one() , p_two() , p_three() : int ref*int ref*int ref ) : unit() =
     ( p_one() , ( !p_two() + !p_one() ) , ( !p_one() + !p_two() + !p_three() )) ;;
```

And the Ocaml interpreter send me this error : Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched  ( with the '(' the third parenthese   ).
I didn't understand why ??

My exercise is :

> Define 3 mutable integer variables: one, two and three. Write an expression (a single expression) accumulate of type unit which updates the 3 variables by accumulating their values. So after execution of the expression, the variable one is unchanged, the variable two contains the sum of the first 2 values, the variable three contains the sum of the 3 values. For example, if we initialize the variables one, two and three respectively with the integer values 1, 2 and 3, after execution these 3 variables contain the values 1, 3 and 6 respectively. Test the accumulate expression on the previous values.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the compiler:

```
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 24-25:
1 | let accumulate() ( p_one() , p_two() , p_three() : int ref*int ref*int ref ) : unit() =
                            ^
Error: Syntax error: ')' expected
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 17-18:
1 | let accumulate() ( p_one() , p_two() , p_three() : int ref*int ref*int ref ) : unit() =
                     ^
  This '(' might be unmatched
```

the pattern `p_one ()` is not syntactically valid, nor is the type `unit ()`.

Answer (score 0):

"Define three integers variables." You've got this mostly figured out. You use `ref` which is good. But you've made two of them *functions*.

```
let p_one = ref 1
let p_two = ref 2
let p_three = ref 3
```

Note: the double semicolons are unnecessary between top-level definitions and the explicit types are unnecessary as these can only be `int ref`.

Your `accumulate` function correctly takes `unit` but doesn't not need to take the other three variables as arguments, nor have you gotten that syntax correct anyway.

So you're left with:

```
let accumulate () =
  ...
```

`!var` is the right way to get the value in a `ref`, but you'll also need `:=` to assign to a `ref` and then `;` to chain two expressions in the one function.

```
let accumulate () =
  p_two := ... + ...;
  ...
```